# Sending over Interface Object from method call hiding implementation super class on server via RMI?

Tags: java, rmi

Say I have class `SuperNode` and an interface `Node`:

```
SuperNode implements Node
```

I have a RMI-Implementation server side and I'm trying to just send the Node over from a method without the user having the source file for SuperNode but they do have the interface Node.

```
public Node RMIImplServer.getNode();
```

When I do this I get this error:

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested
>   exception is:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   SEHT.somepackage.SuperNode (no security manager: RMI class loader
>   disabled)     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getDataNodes(Unknown Source)    Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SEHT.somepackage.SuperNode (no
>   security manager: RMI class loader disabled)  at
>   sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(Unknown Source)  ... 5 more

Is what I'm trying to do possible, if so what am I doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Finally figured it out...the jar file wasn't including the right files due to a stupid default that I didn't check. Thank you so much EJP for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client doesn't need any source files. It does however need the *object* files (.class) files for all types returned by remote methods, available on its CLASSPATH, *unless:*

... if you don't want to deploy `SuperNode.class` or whatever it is at the client, you can use the codebase feature. It's complicated.

1. You will need to install a security manager at the client.
2. You will need to define the system property `java.rmi.server.codebase` at the server JVM.
3. You will need to set it to one or more URLs that are intelligible to the client and that name JAR file(s) containing classes to be loaded dynamically. Typically a codebase item is an HTTP URL. Note that a codebase item referring to the file system local to the server cannot work, as it isn't intelligible to the client.

Comment: Ok thanks, and from your experience with this if you have, is it optimal for my situation or should I take another approach? What is the performance of this like?

Comment: It's useful if you want to retain the freedom to change e.g. `SuperNode` without having to redeploy the client. If that isn't the problem you're trying to solve, what is?

Comment: Right. Also for the security manager, can you be more specific about which one to use and how to implement that please. This does seem like a pretty complicated process though.

Comment: EJP, I've been trying hard to implement a code base and I can't seem to get it working...any suggestions or a place that has up to date information like a tutorial perhaps. I've even looked at suns however the information seems a bit convoluted.  I keep getting a security manager exception after I instantiate one on the client, and I'm confused about the whole permissions aspect etc.

Comment: I told you it's complicated. See the Oracle RMI Tutorial. All you need in the client is `SecurityManager.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());` or even `-Djava.security.manager`. You'll also need to provide a `.policy` file. Run the client with `-Djava.security.debug=access,failure` to see exactly what's going on and what permissions you need to grant yourself.

Comment: Ok I'm getting a new error now I just posted in my OC. I'm trying to direct the codebase to -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Codebase.jar

Comment: Then you didn't read my point 3 above about `file:` URLs on local file systems.